# Grid generation (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I'm new in UWP programming. And have some question.

I have JSON with data (orders). There are some count of orders.

I need to generate Grids with Text fields.

Now I have xaml like this:

```
 <StackPanel Height="1020" Width="350" BorderBrush="#FFFDFCFC" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
            <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="date1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="adress1" TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,146,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="name1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="date2" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" Foreground="White" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="adress2" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,145,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="59" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="name2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,87,-1,0" TextAlignment="Center"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,50"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="date3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" Foreground="White" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="adress3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,143,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="61" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="name3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,50"/>

            </Grid>
            <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="date4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" Foreground="White" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light"  />
                <TextBlock x:Name="adress4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,153,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="61" Width="342" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="name4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,50"/>
            </Grid>
```

And download data to TextBlock like this:

```
try
{
    date1.Text = convertedDate;

    adress1.Text = orders[0].shipping.address_1.ToString() + "                     " + orders[0].shipping.address_2;
    name1.Text = orders[0].billing.first_name.ToString();
    string order =orders[0].ToFormattedJsonString();           
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
}

string date_2 = orders[1].date_created + "+0:00";
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(date_2);
string convertedDate2 = dt2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

try
{
    date2.Text = convertedDate2;
    adress2.Text = orders[1].shipping.address_1.ToString() + "                     " + orders[1].shipping.address_2;
    name2.Text = orders[1].billing.first_name.ToString();
}
catch (Exception e)
{

    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
}
```

But this is not good. How I can count how many json objects in json and generate grids according to it, and after this fill it with data

Comment: This is not the way to go... There are classes for repeating items to avoid exactly this problem (e.g take a look at GridView: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1081343/Implementing-Windows-GridView-for-UWP-Apps )

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to read an article (or a book) on this topic, but here is the a short summery about how to do this.

This is without MVVM, that would be the next step, here I focus on the basics.

So, for repeating items use GridView (Or ListView if that fits better):

```
<GridView Background="Black"  x:Name="OrdersGridView" >
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

As you see we use Data Binding in the DataTemplate (that's the {Binding} stuff).

Then Create a class for the Orders:

```
public class Order {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the code behind behind create a property for the orders:

```
public ObservableCollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

Then populate the orders and set the ItemSource of the GridView to the items (this would be your json fetching code, here I hardcode some stuff to make it easier to understand...):

```
//Populate Orders: 
            Orders = new ObservableCollection<Order> { new Order { Address = "dsfsd", Date = DateTime.Now, Name = "Name" } ,
                 new Order { Address = "dsfsd", Date = DateTime.Now, Name = "Name" },
                  new Order { Address = "dsfsd", Date = DateTime.Now, Name = "Name" }
                };

            OrdersGridView.ItemsSource = Orders;
```

Then you should learn MVVM, but this would be the first step.

Comment: Hello.

look I already have some classes.

I use them for writing data from json to database.

Can I use them?
I add code on link

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6LTX1t5F)

Comment: Sure, you can use them as Model classes.. (as I use the Order class in my sample).

Comment: I have some questions. Where I can contact you?

Comment: Look. I have those classes(you can see it by link) and I make `List` like this.

`List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(products);`

As I understood I need to get count of elements in JSON?

Comment: No, you don't need the count.. that is the point of the GridView control.. it creates as many item as you have in you collection. Look at this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1081343/Implementing-Windows-GridView-for-UWP-Apps

Comment: Hello. I try to do it like you write, but I have trouble. I post it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619137/data-binding-uwpc)

Comment: I have question about your answer. I display `date`. But I need to display data from member of `Billing` class, for example for `last_name`. How I can do this?