# Convert in ObservableCollection (C# uwp)

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I am writing an app for UWP.

I tried to use data binding according to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569914/grid-generation-c-uwp/39571661?noredirect=1#comment66513883_39571661).

Here are my classes:

```
 public class Billing
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string address_1 { get; set; }
        public string address_2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }          
    }

    public class Shipping
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string address_1 { get; set; }
        public string address_2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int parent_id { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }

        public string order_key { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public bool prices_include_tax { get; set; }
        public string date_created { get; set; }
        public string date_modified { get; set; }
        public int customer_id { get; set; }
        public double discount_total { get; set; }
        public double discount_tax { get; set; }
        public double shipping_total { get; set; }
        public double shipping_tax { get; set; }
        public double cart_tax { get; set; }
        public double total { get; set; }
        public double total_tax { get; set; }
        public Billing billing { get; set; }
        public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
        public string payment_method { get; set; }
        public string payment_method_title { get; set; }
        public string transaction_id { get; set; }
        public string customer_ip_address { get; set; }
        public string customer_user_agent { get; set; }
        public string created_via { get; set; }
        public string customer_note { get; set; }
        public string date_completed { get; set; }
        public string date_paid { get; set; }
        public string cart_hash { get; set; }
        public List<object> line_items { get; set; }
        public List<object> tax_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> shipping_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> fee_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> coupon_lines { get; set; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<RootObject> Orders { get; set; }
```

Here is the code:

```
List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(products);
foreach (RootObject root in rootObjectData)
{
    string date = root.date_created;
    string name = root.billing.first_name + root.billing.last_name ;
    Orders = new ObservableCollection<RootObject> { new RootObject { date_created = date,billing = name } };
}
```

With `billing = name` I have this error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Milano.InWork.Billing'`

How can I fix this error?
Maybe this is simple, but I don't find a solution.
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You're trying to assign a string value to a RootObject. Of course this cannot work.

Comment: okay, how I can fix it?@Pierre-LoupPagniez

Comment: Looks to me that there is some problem with the JSON data you are trying to deserialize. What is the content of the "billing" property on the root of the JSON?

Comment: For example 
`"billing": {
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "company": "",
    "address_1": "969 Market",
    "address_2": "",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "postcode": "94103",
    "country": "US",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com",
    "phone": "(555) 555-5555"
  },`

@AldineiSampaio

Comment: What would the result be look like? When You try to set  `root.billing.first_name + root.billing.last_name` to a billing object? Like `Billing billing = "JohnDoe";`

Comment: The error message makes me think there is a string instead of an object on the "billing" property of the JSON. Ex: "billing" : "text inside double quotes". The JSON you posted on last comment is correct, are you sure that is the data that is causing the issue?

Comment: Error in assignment@AldineiSampaio

Comment: I don't know what You would like to achieve. Maybe `Orders = new ObservableCollection<RootObject> (rootObjectData);` outside the foreach? Explain expected result.

Comment: Look I need to bind data. for `date_created ` i use `date`. I need to bind `name` . Name is in `Billing` class and it contains `first_name`+ `Last_name`. How I can bind this one?@ntohl

Answer (score 1):

> With billing = name I have this error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Milano.InWork.Billing'

Of course this error will occur, your `billing` in the class `RootObject` has the data type `Billing`, which is another class you defined.

Just from your code I think you only want to show the `first_name` and `last_name` as string in your `root.billing`, then you can change the code `public Billing billing { get; set; }` in your `RootObject` class to `public string billing { get; set; }`.